# The argument type 'xxx' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget? Function(BuildContext?, Map<String, List<String>>)'

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
import 'package:fluro/fluro.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_scaffold/pages/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_scaffold/pages/incrementCounter/incrementCounter.dart';

var mainHandler = Handler(
   handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, List<String>> params) {
    return HomeScreen();
  }
);

var incrementCounterHandler = Handler(
  handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, List<String>> params) {
    return IncrementCounter(title: '计数');
  }
);
```

[image]

the Handler class:

```dart
class Handler {
  Handler({this.type = HandlerType.route, required this.handlerFunc});
  final HandlerType type;
  final HandlerFunc handlerFunc;
}
typedef Widget? HandlerFunc(
    BuildContext? context, Map<String, List<String>> parameters);
```

I know the argument_type_not_assignable error in a simple way as below

String f(String x) => x;
String g(String y) => f(y);

and common fix as this link

https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages?utm_source=dartdev&utm_medium=redir&utm_id=diagcode&utm_content=argument_type_not_assignable#argument_type_not_assignable

but how to fix the complex type-not-match

homeScreen code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_scaffold/pages/tabA/tabA.dart';
import 'package:flutter_scaffold/pages/tabB/tabB.dart';
import 'package:flutter_scaffold/pages/tabC/tabC.dart';
import 'package:flutter_scaffold/utils/screen_util.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScreen({Key? key, String this.title = ''}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final tabList = [
    TabA(title: 'TabA'),
    TabB(title: 'TabB'),
    TabC(title: 'TabC')
  ];

  changeTab(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScreenUtil.getInstance()
      ..width = 375
      ..height = 812
      ..init(context);

    return Scaffold(
      body: tabList[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: (int index) => changeTab(index),
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'tabA', icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'tabB', icon: Icon(Icons.book)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: 'tabC', icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

one answer say I can assert type like this（I understand this action,since typescript has the same syntax）

```dart
return HomeScreen() as Widget? Function(BuildContext?, Map<String, List<String>>);
```

one error turns into two

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```dart
var mainHandler = Handler(
    handlerFunc: (BuildContext? context, Map<String, List<String>> params) {
  return HomeScreen();
});

var incrementCounterHandler = Handler(
    handlerFunc: (BuildContext? context, Map<String, List<String>> params) {
  return IncrementCounter(title: '计数');
});
```

all right, BuildContext can be null cause this error,just add a ? between BuildContext and context。